# Getting an array of each directory in string with Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to parse out all of the directories in a string (which I'm getting from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) into an array. The regex code I have currently works to get the last directory, but I want to match *all* of the directories.

Here is a sample string:

```
/index.php/test/test1/test2/test3
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
\/index\.php\/(?:([a-z0-9]+)\/*)+
```

Comment: The most easy way is to get all the path and then split with `/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why regex?

```
$paths = explode('/', trim($string, '/'));
```

Comment: Hmm yeah I can't think of a good reason not to do that... so sure... But just for the sake of learning, how would I do it with regex?

Comment: `index.php` is not a directory. Wrap `explode` in `array_slice`.

Comment: If there will always be a php filename then just ignore index 0 or shift it.